# SSRS-design report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have SQL results that I wish to display, each person has different activity, price for each activity plus charges. I with to group them together by person ( see the image attached). The highlighted results in yellow color it should be my final report. Please can you help.
Blessed

SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Surname, TypeParticipant, i.IDBill, ip.Idparticipant, cast((f.couttotal / 100.0) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) AS price, left(f.texte, 20) AS ActivityName, a.Activityfee, convert(VARCHAR, g.datedebut, 111) DateDébut, convert(VARCHAR, g.datefin, 111) DateFIn
FROM Fin.FactureItem i
LEFT JOIN ins.Inscription ip
    ON ip.Idinscription = i.IDinscription
LEFT JOIN Fin.FactureItem f
    ON f.IDfacture = i.IDfacture
INNER JOIN Part.participant p
    ON p.idparticipant = ip.idparticipant
INNER JOIN Acts.Groupe g
    ON g.idgroupe = ip.idgroupe
INNER JOIN Acts.Activite a
    ON a.idactivite = g.idactivite
INNER JOIN Part.ParticipantTypeParticipant t
    ON p.idparticipant = t.idparticipant – Blessed 11 secs ago
INNER JOIN Part.TypeParticipant ct
    ON ct.idtypeparticipant = t.idtypeparticipant
WHERE i.IDfacture IS NOT NULL
    AND i.idinscription IS NOT NULL
    AND p.idparticipant IN (
        45103
        ,12354
        )
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qdro.jpg)

Comment: please add your sql query, most people prefer formatted text to Images and please be specific and a good read on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello B house Here is my query

Comment: Cant see your query yet

Comment: I am getting trouble to post it because of format issues

Comment: I will write a solution for you based on what i see expected output in Image

Comment: Do u have from and to dates in the query

Comment: from FIn.FactureItem i 
 left join Insc.Inscription ip 
 on ip.Idinscription = i.IDinscription 
 left join Fin.FactureItem f on f.IDfacture = i.IDfacture
 inner join Part.participant p
 on p.idparticipant=ip.idparticipant 
 inner join Acts.Groupe g
on g.idgroupe=ip.idgroupe
inner join Acts.Activite a
on a.idactivite=g.idactivite
inner join  Part.ParticipantTypeParticipant t 
on p.idparticipant=t.idparticipant
inner join Part.TypeParticipant ct

Comment: on ct.idtypeparticipant=t.idtypeparticipant
 where i.IDfacture is not null and i.idinscription is not null

Comment: select 
distinct
Name
,Surname
, TypeParticipant
,i.IDBill
,ip.Idparticipant
,cast( (f.couttotal / 100.0) as decimal(20, 2)) as price
,left(f.texte,20) AS ActivityandFees
,a.ActivityName
,convert(varchar, g.datedebut, 111) DateDébut
,convert(varchar, g.datefin, 111)DateFIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need `aggregation` by all other columns. This will work based on your output in `image`. however, i believe top value should be $230. Anyways depending on our output, i would need to modify the query. You might need further sub queries.

```
     WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT nom
        ,prenom
        ,TitreFRA AS TypeParticipant
        ,i.IDfacture AS IDBill
        ,ip.Idparticipant
        ,cast((f.couttotal / 100.0) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) AS price
        ,left(f.texte, 20) AS Activityandfees
        ,a.nomFra Activityname
        ,convert(VARCHAR, g.datedebut, 111) DateDébut
        ,convert(VARCHAR, g.datefin, 111) DateFIn
    FROM Finances.FactureItem i
    LEFT JOIN Inscriptions.Inscription ip ON ip.Idinscription = i.IDinscription
    LEFT JOIN Finances.FactureItem f ON f.IDfacture = i.IDfacture
    INNER JOIN participants.participant p ON p.idparticipant = ip.idparticipant
    INNER JOIN Activites.Groupe g ON g.idgroupe = ip.idgroupe
    INNER JOIN Activites.Activite a ON a.idactivite = g.idactivite
    INNER JOIN Participants.ParticipantTypeParticipant t ON p.idparticipant = t.idparticipant
    INNER JOIN participants.TypeParticipant ct ON ct.idtypeparticipant = t.idtypeparticipant
    WHERE i.IDfacture IS NOT NULL AND i.idinscription IS NOT NULL AND p.idparticipant IN (
            4513
            ,12354
            )
    )
    ,CT1
AS (
    SELECT nom
        ,prenom
        ,TypeParticipant
        ,Activityname
        ,DateDébut
        ,Activityandfees
        ,price
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ACTIVITYANDFEES
             ORDER BY ACTIVITYNAME DESC
            ) rn
    FROM cte
    )
    ,ct2
AS (
    SELECT NOM
        ,PRENOM
        ,TYPEPARTICIPANT
        ,ACTIVITINAME
        ,Price
        ,0 Price1
        ,0 price2
        ,0 price3
      FROM ct1
      WHERE Activityandfees = 'Ajout de I Activite' AND rn = 1
    UNION ALL

    SELECT NOM
        ,PRENOM
        ,TYPEPARTICIPANT
        ,ACTIVITINAME
        ,0 Price
        ,price price1
        ,0 price2
        ,0 price3

    FROM ct1
    WHERE Activityandfees = 'Frias daccompagname' AND rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NOM
        ,PRENOM
        ,TYPEPARTICIPANT
        ,ACTIVITINAME
        ,0 Price
        ,0 price1
        ,price price2
        ,0 price3

    FROM ct1
      WHERE Activityandfees = 'Frias dinscription' AND rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NOM
        ,PRENOM
        ,TYPEPARTICIPANT
        ,ACTIVITINAME
        ,0 Price
        ,0 price1
        ,0 price2
        ,price Price3

    FROM ct1
    WHERE Activityandfees = 'Subvention' AND rn = 1
    )
SELECT NOM
    ,PRENOM
    ,TYPEPARTICIPANT
    ,ACTIVITINAME
    ,sum(cast(price as float)) AjoutActivityprice
    ,sum(cast(price1 as float)) daccompagnameActivityprice
    ,sum(cast(price2 as float)) dinscriptionActivityprice
    ,sum(cast(price3 as float)) Subventionprice
FROM ct2
GROUP BY NOM
    ,PRENOM
    ,TYPEPARTICIPANT
    ,ACTIVITINAME
```

Comment: Thank You B House. I am going to test your query and let you what I am getting at my end.

Comment: @B House: Please your query answered one thing but I am having trouble with max function. Because each activity has its own price. Then when I use max, all activities are having the same price. The same thing for the fees. How can I correct that please? Thank You

Comment: when u use `max` with case expression, each max price will be returned for each activity

Comment: For exemple AjoutActivityprice has different values for each activity. Using max, I am ending with the same price for all activity. the same thing for subvention price. It may different from one activity to another. How can I handle this issue please? Thank you.

Comment: So if activityname = 'Ajout de I Activite' is one activity if it has 3 different values what value do u like to choose and what are rules around it ? do u like sum of all values or take highest value from activity or take value from Datefln, add some sample data, i can work around it for you

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAiLG.jpg  Please click on this link for Excel results. When you look at column ActivityName you shall notice that we have 3 different activities and each activity has its own price. So I can not sum them. I have to display every activity with its price. At the end I will do a sum to see how much this person paid in total minus the fees that are sponsored.

Comment: Activity1 is 200$, activity2 is 220 and activity3 is 230. Thank You

Comment: so  activityname academynimitennis = 200, activityname petitscusitos = 220 and activityname Tout-En-Camp = 230. is it righ t?

Comment: Here are the prices per activiy: activityname academynimitennis = 230, activityname petitscusitos = 220 and activityname Tout-En-Camp = 200.

Comment: how would u select random price in each activity , tout-en_Camp has 200,220 and 230. what is rule around it to select 200

Comment: Actually, that is my challenge for now. Two columns fee and activity Because I have activities and fees plus their prices. Son when I am displaying my results, every activity will be repeated for each record from the column fees. For exemple price 230$ will appears more than once. May be because I ve to go and fetch their prices from Bill Table? Thank You.

Comment: As you can see All have the same bill ID

Comment: I guess u are selecting price per activity based on rownumber by activity name, let me find a solution, will replay back bit later when i am home in an hour

Comment: I have bills from bills I can know the activity and price plus the person who does the activity. Then in one bill, the payment may refer to one or more activities plus the fees.  i will wait for your solution. Thank You.

Comment: That's right. For each person, we have same for all entries.

Comment: @Blessed          I have amended the script, try this now.

Comment: I m gonna run the script and will let you know. Thank You.

Comment: I am getting syntax error and looking how to handle that: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 51
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 64
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 77
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 90
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Comment: click on the error message , it directs u to the error location

Comment: @Blessed i guess u have some other script in query window

Comment: I guess it is from followed by UNION ALL that gives trouble

Comment: I only have your script. The problem comes from this part. Where followed by From and Union all

Comment: @Blessed   I have seen that a typo, where comes after from table name, updated script now

Comment: Work. Just handling one more error:Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @Blessed i think price is stored as varchar datatype, i have casted it to Float, check now

Comment: The problem come to where you set the price to  empty and union all. I am trying to correct it and getting some error Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 100
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.
 Because I replace one price in a wrong way

Comment: ,ct2
AS (
    SELECT NOM
        ,PRENOM
        ,TYPEPARTICIPANT
        ,ACTIVITYNAME
        ,Price
        ,'' Price1
        ,'' price2
        ,'' price3
      FROM ct1
      WHERE Activityandfees = 'Ajout de I Activite' AND rn = 1
    UNION ALL

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
Invalid column name 'Price'.

Comment: Ct1 misses column price.

Comment: I put price and run the query getting this error Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Guessing that problem comes from price aliases

Comment: same error Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: replaced empty strings in price with 0, as i dont have sample data in text format, i have assumed the query mainly. Try again this time

Comment: GOOD! It is working. However it is giving me one row which means one activity and the price of activity is zero.

Comment: post the output here please

Comment: NOM PRENOM TYPEPARTICIPANT ACTIVITYNAME AjoutActivityprice daccompagnameActivityprice dinscriptionActivityprice Subventionprice
Abraham White Bordeaux-Cartierville Tout-un-camp 0 50 25 0

Comment: @Blessed you should be getting 200-50-0-191.66 for tout-en-camp

Comment: True. But it is not the case now. Something somewhere hidden causes the issue

Comment: @Blessed comment out that part of query and check if other ones giving required output, i have to be in your environment to check exactly whats causing this

Comment: Sure. I will let you know.

Comment: I found the problem. However How can i loop through. Cz it is bringing out one row when rn=1 and it is stack for the rest see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYKYP.jpg

Comment: @Blessed change it to partition by activityandfees,activityname

Comment: Good! It works very well. The problem remaining is order by cause the price are misplaced.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qdro.jpg here are the results when i partitioned by  by activityandfees,activityname order by activityname. I have a problem with price that are not following. Otherwise all is well.

Comment: @Blessed there should be some `id` column to order by, because u will get $200 for each for row1, you will need 220,230,200 right

Comment: @Blessed you might need to hardcode row number in union all, first one  rn=1 and second one rn=2 and thirs one rn= 3 in where clause, try the combinations

Comment: Good! I will let you know! Thank You!

Comment: @B House, I am still trying the combination but no good answer yet. Thank You.

Comment: @VenThank you so much B House. Your answer resolved my problem. Very perfect. Thank You

Comment: @Blessed Not a problem, please let me know if you are struck in any solution

Comment: Thank You. Sure, I will. Please I would like to know if you have some hints for me I wish to improve my SQL programming Skills, are there some helpful tutorial or guideline you can advice?

Comment: @Blessed There are lot of resources available in web, but i would say stick to one until u get familiar with programming skills. Kris@essentialsql.com looks to be best and effective learning method

Comment: Good! Thank You! I will have a look on that.